# How can i test a quickbooks QBXML and the validity of the tags

Tags: java, testing, quickbooks, qbxml

I am new to quickbooks, i tried to use the XML i have written to integrate with quickbooks 12.0,but it failed yesterday in the live environment,

> **Error**
>
> 0x80040400 QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML
>   text stream.

I have attached the XML i have used

Can someone tell me if i there is a way i can test this before trying it in the live environment?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the XML schema or DTD for the Quickbooks XML format?

Comment: [This page](http://consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbxml) looks like it would help you out.

Comment: @chrylis no, i do not have it..

Comment: Thanks @UFL1138 , i have modified my xml based on the developer guide i need help in testing the new XML

Comment: Do you have access to the Quick Books SDK?

Answer (score 5):

Use the validator program that is shipped with the SDK.

Comment: +1 If you use the validator, it will tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks @William Lorfing,

Comment: @consolibyte..Thanks .. i did not know how to use the validator, i ended up creating a fake qwb file inorder to test my XMl.. How can i use the validator?

Answer (score 5):

Posting this for others. The validator is typically installed here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\IDN\Common\tools\validator\qbValidator.exe

Answer (score 2):

You can only test in a local setup ( quickbooks desktop version ).
i have checked the above xml RefNumber tag should be outside CustomerRef

You can also verify the xml tags from onscreen reference.
https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

## Here is the sample xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<InvoiceAddRq>
<InvoiceAdd defMacro="MACROTYPE"> <!-- required -->
<CustomerRef> <!-- required -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</CustomerRef>
<ClassRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</ClassRef>
<ARAccountRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</ARAccountRef>
<TemplateRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</TemplateRef>
<TxnDate >DATETYPE</TxnDate> <!-- optional -->
<RefNumber >STRTYPE</RefNumber> <!-- optional -->
<BillAddress> <!-- optional -->
<Addr1 >STRTYPE</Addr1> <!-- optional -->
<Addr2 >STRTYPE</Addr2> <!-- optional -->
<Addr3 >STRTYPE</Addr3> <!-- optional -->
<Addr4 >STRTYPE</Addr4> <!-- optional -->
<Addr5 >STRTYPE</Addr5> <!-- optional -->
<City >STRTYPE</City> <!-- optional -->
<State >STRTYPE</State> <!-- optional -->
<PostalCode >STRTYPE</PostalCode> <!-- optional -->
<Country >STRTYPE</Country> <!-- optional -->
<Note >STRTYPE</Note> <!-- optional -->
</BillAddress>
<ShipAddress> <!-- optional -->
<Addr1 >STRTYPE</Addr1> <!-- optional -->
<Addr2 >STRTYPE</Addr2> <!-- optional -->
<Addr3 >STRTYPE</Addr3> <!-- optional -->
<Addr4 >STRTYPE</Addr4> <!-- optional -->
<Addr5 >STRTYPE</Addr5> <!-- optional -->
<City >STRTYPE</City> <!-- optional -->
<State >STRTYPE</State> <!-- optional -->
<PostalCode >STRTYPE</PostalCode> <!-- optional -->
<Country >STRTYPE</Country> <!-- optional -->
<Note >STRTYPE</Note> <!-- optional -->
</ShipAddress>
<IsPending >BOOLTYPE</IsPending> <!-- optional -->
<IsFinanceCharge >BOOLTYPE</IsFinanceCharge> <!-- optional -->
<PONumber >STRTYPE</PONumber> <!-- optional -->
<TermsRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</TermsRef>
<DueDate >DATETYPE</DueDate> <!-- optional -->
<SalesRepRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</SalesRepRef>
<FOB >STRTYPE</FOB> <!-- optional -->
<ShipDate >DATETYPE</ShipDate> <!-- optional -->
<ShipMethodRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</ShipMethodRef>
<ItemSalesTaxRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</ItemSalesTaxRef>
<Memo >STRTYPE</Memo> <!-- optional -->
<CustomerMsgRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</CustomerMsgRef>
<IsToBePrinted >BOOLTYPE</IsToBePrinted> <!-- optional -->
<IsToBeEmailed >BOOLTYPE</IsToBeEmailed> <!-- optional -->
<CustomerSalesTaxCodeRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</CustomerSalesTaxCodeRef>
<Other >STRTYPE</Other> <!-- optional -->
<ExchangeRate >FLOATTYPE</ExchangeRate> <!-- optional -->
<ExternalGUID >GUIDTYPE</ExternalGUID> <!-- optional -->
<LinkToTxnID >IDTYPE</LinkToTxnID> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<SetCredit> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<CreditTxnID useMacro="MACROTYPE">IDTYPE</CreditTxnID> <!-- required -->
<AppliedAmount >AMTTYPE</AppliedAmount> <!-- required -->
<Override >BOOLTYPE</Override> <!-- optional -->
</SetCredit>
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<InvoiceLineAdd defMacro="MACROTYPE"> <!-- optional -->
<ItemRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</ItemRef>
<Desc >STRTYPE</Desc> <!-- optional -->
<Quantity >QUANTYPE</Quantity> <!-- optional -->
<UnitOfMeasure >STRTYPE</UnitOfMeasure> <!-- optional -->
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<Rate >PRICETYPE</Rate> <!-- optional -->
<!-- OR -->
<RatePercent >PERCENTTYPE</RatePercent> <!-- optional -->
<!-- OR -->
<PriceLevelRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</PriceLevelRef>
<!-- END OR -->
<ClassRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</ClassRef>
<Amount >AMTTYPE</Amount> <!-- optional -->
<InventorySiteRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</InventorySiteRef>
<InventorySiteLocationRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</InventorySiteLocationRef>
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<SerialNumber >STRTYPE</SerialNumber> <!-- optional -->
<!-- OR -->
<LotNumber >STRTYPE</LotNumber> <!-- optional -->
<!-- END OR -->
<ServiceDate >DATETYPE</ServiceDate> <!-- optional -->
<SalesTaxCodeRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</SalesTaxCodeRef>
<OverrideItemAccountRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</OverrideItemAccountRef>
<Other1 >STRTYPE</Other1> <!-- optional -->
<Other2 >STRTYPE</Other2> <!-- optional -->
<LinkToTxn> <!-- optional -->
<TxnID >IDTYPE</TxnID> <!-- required -->
<TxnLineID >IDTYPE</TxnLineID> <!-- required -->
</LinkToTxn>
<DataExt> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<OwnerID >GUIDTYPE</OwnerID> <!-- required -->
<DataExtName >STRTYPE</DataExtName> <!-- required -->
<DataExtValue >STRTYPE</DataExtValue> <!-- required -->
</DataExt>
</InvoiceLineAdd>
<!-- OR -->
<InvoiceLineGroupAdd> <!-- optional -->
<ItemGroupRef> <!-- required -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</ItemGroupRef>
<Quantity >QUANTYPE</Quantity> <!-- optional -->
<UnitOfMeasure >STRTYPE</UnitOfMeasure> <!-- optional -->
<InventorySiteRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</InventorySiteRef>
<InventorySiteLocationRef> <!-- optional -->
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional -->
<FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional -->
</InventorySiteLocationRef>
<DataExt> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<OwnerID >GUIDTYPE</OwnerID> <!-- required -->
<DataExtName >STRTYPE</DataExtName> <!-- required -->
<DataExtValue >STRTYPE</DataExtValue> <!-- required -->
</DataExt>
</InvoiceLineGroupAdd>
<!-- END OR -->
</InvoiceAdd>
<IncludeRetElement >STRTYPE</IncludeRetElement> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
</InvoiceAddRq>
```

Comment: Thanks, i did look at the above link and figure out the mistake with RefNumber tag, but i do not know where and how i can test the new  XML i have.

Comment: Is there anyone still active?